# $.getJSON returns undefined when result > 199

Tags: mysql, json

Retrieving data from a mysql table via $.getJSON. This works good, however, when the dataset is larger than 199 records, the result displays "undefined" starting from 200 en up. It is not an issue with the data (I think) because when I reverse my order in the query, the data that was previously "undefined" at the end of the list is now fully readable at the top of the list and the data at the bottom that was fine in the first place is now "undefined".

```
$.getJSON("", {a:'data',order_by:orderby}, function (data) {
   if(data) {
      $.each(data.data, function (i, data) {
         ...  // nothing special here, just format and output the data to a table
      }
   }
}
```

To retrieve the data:

```
$result = $con->query("select t1.id ...");

if($con->numRows($result)) {
   while($aData = $con->fetchAssoc($result)) {
      $aData = utf8_json($aData);
      $data[] = $aData;
   }
}

echo json_encode(array('data'=>$data));
```

Any thoughts?

SQL statement:

```
select t1.id, t1.klnr, t1.soort, t1.datum, t1.tijd, t1.flag_afgesloten,flag_opvolging,
 t2.lijn1, t2.lijn2, t2.lijn3, t2.lijn4, t2.telefoon, t2.gsm, t1.sig, t1.gemaild, 
 t1.gemaildnaar, t1.flag_gefactureerd, t1.flag_delstatus
from bon_v1 t1 left join pp_klanten t2 on t1.klnr = t2.nr
where t1.flag_live = 1 
order by " . $orderby . ";"
```

I also tried returning fixed values instead of the data from the table: this also results in a "undefined" starting from record 200

Comment: Please post your SELECT query and table structre, maybe with some sample values. jQuery and PHP are most probably not causing this.

Comment: SQL statement added + info about a test I just ran with fixed values instead of values from the mysql database.

Comment: we need a simple example which reproduces the problem. at least locate where the problem is. if SQL is not relevant to the problem, get rid of it (generate fake result with a loop). check the generated json output, etc.

Comment: We still can't see your data, which seems to be the cause of your problems. Can you show us the output of your PHP? The generated JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I Believe it's because your bon_v1 Table have some data than pp_klanten table won't get corresponding records,commonly say is left table have datas more than right table,try to search the difference between "left join " and "right join" of Sql statement..